# Is it legal for zip central directory to not list middle folders?

Tags: zip

A zip file has headers for each file in the zip called a Central Directory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Central_directory_file_header

However this does not define whether a zip containing one file e.g. "foo/bar/baz.txt" can have only one entry, or must the folders also have entries? I couldn't find an answer either in the APPNOTE

The answer would help determine which implementations of zip entry processing are correct in some Java API-s. E.g. how to correctly determine all 1 level deep entries in a zip subfolder.

```
Set<String> getResourcePaths(String path) {
  //???
}
getResourcePaths("/foo") -> ["/foo/bar"]
```

Which of these are allowed either according to zip spec or most commonly acceptable by various zipping, unzipping and (sub)entry listing tools?

**A:**

```
foo/
foo/bar/
foo/bar/baz.txt
```

**B:**

```
foo/
foo/bar/baz.txt
```

**C:**

```
foo/bar/baz.txt
```

The initial issue was that a java jar did not contain **some**(option B in this case) directory entries, however code listing zip entries assumed these were present so eventually leading to the resource to be not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's more a matter of how unzipper handles it. Anyway: the standard unix zip program has an option -D which ignores the empty directory paths. 
This is how you can preview it in mc:

[image]

The same file created without option -D:

[image]

Of course, you can unzip them with any tool I know (unzip, build-in windows tool, 7z), so I would say programs are going to handle it.

But if for any reason in your case it's better to keep all sub-paths - let's do it.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the -D option in zip. I clarified the question a bit to indicate i was looking for an answer on correct ways to parse the central directory, e.g. determine 1 level deep entries in a (sub)folder. However the existence of such a flag essentially indicates that it's certainly valid and it's a bug in the parsing code for making incorrect assumptions.